# Are wall-mounted urinals more sanitary than floor mounted units?

Tags: technology, toilets

Men's urinals can either be mounted on a wall, or can extend all the way to the floor.

According to this [page](http://www.keidel.com/select/urinal.htm), floor mounted urinals are less desirable because:

> Floor Mount
>
> - These units are tall (36" - 40") and have the bowl and drain on the floor.
> - Harder for men to use than standard height wall mount.
> - Spots and splashes on the floor are common place.

Along these lines I have also often heard the charge they are "less sanitary"

In my experience, however, it seems like there is always a puddle beneath the wall mounted unit. Along these lines, a floor mounted unit should be more sanitary, because more of the drips that would otherwise go on the floor would still end up within the porcelain.

So, with this argument in mind, why is it so rare in the United States to see a floor mounted unit, and why are wall-mounted units considered to be more sanitary?

Comment: Purely anecdotal, but if you're asking this question then you obviously haven't used many full-height, floor-mounted units. You many see the odd drip on the floor of a wall-mounted, waist-height unit, but the floor around a full-height floor-mounted urinal is normally sodden. A lot of the older, traditional pubs and clubs in the UK have the full-height variety and are slowly changing over to wall-mounts. My guess would be there's far more chance of splash-back (particularly by the inebriated) from a flat, vertical wall and trough, than a curved bowl.

Comment: The floor is being mopped anyway, and wall-mounted means that there is no "seam" at the floor to collect or hold splashes that seep underneath. The urinal is smaller, so there is less to clean. **The bowl is closer to where the urine originates**, so aiming is easier. Wow, I barely remember the old floor level trough ones... Must be some reasons.

Answer (score -2):

They have their controversies each. Wall urinals are often cheaper believe it or not for some reason although they are exposed - they have a bit more wall around them. Floor urinals are even more exposed so the whole place can see you peeing from further away although a wall one is visible aswell. Floor ones are more durable in quality although the maintenance has been questioned and moisture near the floor area where the pee runs down to the floor has been seen as not being sanitary by some although many have lasted a good long time. Floor ones are better for user versatility as they take into consideration the height of the people though may be harder for people with leg problems. Each type has its advantage

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.